# Footable Sorting Issue with text value '05.04.2018 19:15'

Tags: sorting, footable

I have a (footable) table with a text column in the format of a datetimestamp like:

```
05.04.2018 19:00
09.06.2018 20:00
10.06.2018 19:00
```

I would like to sort this table by the column value, but it is not working. Supplying a sortValue like 201804051900 doesn't work either.

All my data is loaded by jquery executing a php-file on the server. The Date/Time Colum is loaded in the format:

```
$cols[$i]['name']="sp_timestamp"; 
$cols[$i]['title']="Datum/Zeit"; 
$cols[$i]['sorted']=true; 
$cols[$i]['direction']="DESC";
```

and the row as:

```
$rows[$key]['sp_timestamp']['options']['sortValue']='201804051900';
$rows[$key]['sp_timestamp']['value']='05.04.2018 19:00';
```

`$i` and `$key` are just indexes of the iterator in the php.

Can anyone help me please?

EDIT: 
Edit: By ivestigating footable.js i have found following behaviour. I have printed out the parameters of `F.Column.prototype.sorter` to the console. It seems that on initial load of the table `sortValue` is used properly. Any further sorting makes NOT use of `sortValue`, but of the column value itself. In the DOM the data-sort-value attribute is NOT set. As far as i understand the docs, this seems to be a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution:
I have changed the F.Column.prototype.sorter to solve my problem quickly using momentjs to format the strings properly. But this is only a workaround.

```
F.Column.prototype.sorter = function(a, b){
        if ($.isNumeric(a)) {a=parseInt(a,10);} else if (typeof a === 'string') {a = a.toLowerCase()};
        if ($.isNumeric(b)) {b=parseInt(b,10);} else if (typeof b === 'string') {b = b.toLowerCase()};

        var m_a=moment(a, 'L LT');
        var m_b=moment(b, 'L LT');
        if (m_a.isValid()) {a=m_a.format('YYYYMMDDHHmm');}
        if (m_b.isValid()) {b=m_b.format('YYYYMMDDHHmm');}

        if (a === b) return 0;
        if (a < b) return -1;
        return 1;
    };
```

As you can see I have additonally overridden the default string sorting if the sortvalue is numeric.